# DataWarehouse test automation

Tags: testing, automation, db2, etl, data-warehouse

What is the best way and what tools are available to automate testing of stored procedures (run in sequences during the ETL process by a scheduler) in a large data warehouse environment?

Answer (score 1):

This area is quite broad for a single answer post. I'm currently responsible for such ETL/DW tests, so I'll share my experience. My approach is to spin the Test framework around the used by our DEVs tool. The QA approach can be found all over the Web, but sadly no common Test framework is there out-of-the-box. Take a look at [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/dwh/dwh_testing.htm) and [this](http://www.querysurge.com/solutions/data-warehouse-testing). Another useful thing is the checklists like [this one](http://www.softwaretestingtimes.com/2010/04/checklist-for-data-warehouse-testing.html) or [this one](http://www.qaiglobalservices.com/conference/stc2013/PDFs/Prasuna_Potteti_1.pdf).  Last but not least you can use such frameworks like [tSQLt](http://tsqlt.org/) for the MS SQL

> automate testing of stored procedures

Actually the domain knowledge is the most important part here.

Comment: thanks for this, I will go through them and let you know

Comment: Please do - I definitely think that this question should be extended.

Comment: I am trying to use Fitnesse/DBFit

Answer (score 0):

Automate testing in DB2's SQL PL can be done with the unit testing framework [https://github.com/angoca/db2unit](https://angoca.github.io/db2unit/). This framework allows you to deal with database basic data types; however, you can create your [own assertions](https://github.com/angoca/db2unit/wiki/Custom-assert) and add them in the framework.

If you find it useful but you need more features, you can [create an issue](https://github.com/angoca/db2unit/issues) explaining what you need.

I am the main developer of that project, and I am looking new ways this project can be used.

Comment: Sure I will look into this, can it be used to test a set of stored procedures that read from a number of tables and write in an output table as part of an ETL overnight job?

Comment: I do not know what exactly you want to do. If you prefer, create an issue in GitHub, instead of discuss this here.